# jQueryUI effects on table columns

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Trying to use jQueryUI to slide a table column out of view, and then back in.  Sadly, it does not appear to retain the correct column widths and positions, so the column ends up in the wrong place.

The distilled version of the problem I'm hitting is at http://jsfiddle.net/Z76xE/6/ .  I've seen a number of different variants of undesired behavior, but the straightforward case pointed to here only gets confused on the expand operation: it first expands the column to be bigger than the 150px that the CSS fixes it to be, and then at the end snaps its left edge over to make the column 150px again, leaving empty white space on the left side of the table.

In endless hours of playing with this and tracing through JavaScript, I've realized that jQuery is getting a different column width than the CSS declared.  So I'm doing something wrong in [not] telling jQuery / jQueryUI to update its understanding of column widths.  I just don't know where!

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: i cant reproduce the white space.. what browser?

Comment: Have you tried with display block applied to #navColumn?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: I can get the funky layout in Safari.

Comment: Indeed, I did most testing on Safari, though earlier (less streamlined and clear) versions also had undesired effects on Firefox.  As the answer-er below notes, by sticking the <div> around the <td>, we launch into All Bets Are Off territory, so browser behavior was likely to change chaotically --- even into correct behavior sometimes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch your animation with your DOM inspector open, you'll see that the `<td>` gets wrapped in a `<div>` and that `<div>` gets animated. However, this:

```
<tr>
    <div>
        <td></td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

is invalid HTML so who knows what sort of strange and wonderful things the browser is going to with that. We do know one strange thing that it will do with that: it will leave the `<td>` in the wrong place when you animate it open.

Messing around with positioning and display of table elements is a bit of a nightmare so you're better off avoiding it. If you change your HTML to this:

```
<td>
    <div id="NavColumn">
        I am the left-side column
    </div>
</td>
```

then you'll have better luck: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VUvCw/

You'll have to adjust the CSS a bit to get the visual layout you want but that structure should get your animation sorted out.

Comment: That was it ... thanks!  For all the debug screens I went to, I couldn't catch the behavior you describe --- so in addition to this answer, thank you for teaching me the key phrase "DOM Inspector".  Sadly, moving to <div>'s from the table costs me other elegance of formatting, so now I'm down to deciding which inelegance is best.  Sigh; I'm not the first person to struggle with getting a three-column format to behave cleanly, and shan't be the last.  Thanks again for the quick and clear help!

Comment: Wait ... correction ... I misread; you are keeping the table format --- yay!  I swear I actually tried exactly this, and got different behavior (the text disappeared but the column just remained blank).  Must have fat-fingered something --- this is perfect!